# File not displayed using vi but visible with command ls -l CD*

Tags: files, ls

I can do an `ls -l CD*` and see the following output.

`CDTEST userA RW RW R`

I am logged in as userA. But if I do an `ls -l` the file does not appear. If I do  `vi CDTEST` it tries to create a new file named `CDTEST`. If I do a `mv` or `rm` I get the message no file of name `CDTEST` found.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have some directory that matches `CD*`. When you run `ls -l CD*` you're seeing the contents of this directory, which includes the file `CDTEST`.

#### Example

Say I had this directory structure.

```
$ tree .
.
`-- CD1
    `-- CDTEST

1 directory, 1 file
```

If I run the following command from the same location:

```
$ ls -l CD*
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Mar 25 21:41 CDTEST
```

You can get a list of actual directories if you add the `-d` switch to `ls`.

```
$ ls -ld CD*
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Mar 25 21:45 CD1
```

When you run your commands they're with respect to the directory that contains `CD1`, which has no file by the name of `CDTEST`. You can also check what's in your current directory like this:

```
$ ls -l
```

Or you can filter it using `grep` like this:

```
$ ls -l | grep CD
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Mar 25 21:45 CD1
```

**NOTE:** Notice that `CD1` has a `d` at the beginning? That tells you it's a directory.

Comment: Nice explanation. It is the best way to explain things to new users :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the **CDTEST** file appears to be inside a folder. When you issue the command,

```
ls -l CD*
```

The above command actually displays a file **CDTEST** inside your folder which is not present in the present working directory. So, if you do `ls -l` it would not display the **CDTEST** file which is inside the folder. And that is the reason a new file is getting created when you do `vi CDTEST` or `no file found` error occurs when you issue the command `mv` or `rm`.

You are probably issuing the `vi`, `mv` or `rm` command from the `pwd`.